# Is it possible to set the initial topic assignments for scikit-learn LDA?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, lda, latent-semantic-analysis

Instead of setting the topic_word_prior as a parameter, I would like to initialize the topics according to a pre-defined distribution over words.  How would I set this initial topic distribution in sklearn's implementation? If it's not possible, is there a better implementation to consider?

Comment: I'd also like to note that you should check out pickle for this.  It saves the model as a file for accessibility:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a predefined distribution of words in a pre-trained model you can just pass a bow_corpus through that distribution as a function.  Gensims LDA and LDAMallet can both be trained once then you can pass a new data set through for allocation without changing the topics.

Steps:

1. Import your data
2. Clean your data: nix punctuation, numbers, lemmatize, remove stop-words, and stem
3. Create a dictionary

   ```
   dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(processed_docs[:])
   dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=15, no_above=0.5, keep_n=100000)
   ```
4. Define a bow corpus

   ```
   bow_corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in processed_docs]
   ```
5. Train your model - skip if it's already trained

   ```
   ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, 
               corpus=bow_corpus, num_topics=15, id2word=dictionary)
   ```
6. Import your new data and follow steps 1-4
7. Pass your new data through your model like this:

   ```
     ldamallet[bow_corpus_new[:len(bow_corpus_new)]]
   ```
8. Your new data is allocated now and you can put it in a CSV

Comment: Just to verify I understand you correctly, you're suggesting to 
1) generate a bunch of sample (bag of word) documents using the pre-defined distribution, then 
2) train the LDA on the predefined corpus, and finally 
3) use that model as the starting point for a model trained on the actual data?

Comment: @ComplexGates I added a short breakdown of the procedure I hope it helped to clarify :)